# Redux server-rendering => not responding to state changes

Tags: reactjs, redux

After the initial render, state does not update the UI until I navigate back to the root directory (where the refresh occurs)

This is problematic because when I make async calls/changes to state in the root directory, I expect the navigated window to reflect the updated state change.

I believe this is because the initial state loading/server rendering occurs at root and isn't updating appropriately.

I have looked into using store.subscribe(render), but per Redux docs:

> // You can use subscribe() to update the UI in response to state
>   changes such as React Redux rather than subscribe() directly.
>
> //Normally you’d use a view binding library (e.g. React

I have also tried using componentWillMount, but this doesn't make a lot of sense to me (nor does it work).

TLDR:

State change in root components do not propagate down to sub components (though they are reflected on the root component level)

I can only get a render when any async action is not involved (i.e. I keep a copy of the async data structure in memory, mutate, then reduce it)

**Solutions**

1. This is likely because after the initial async fetch, I am not calling "fetch" again after the async call. I initialize another fetch after making my async call.
2. I keep "client-side" state in memory and write to DB simultaneously. I don't like this because it seems highly susceptible to inconsistencies between state tree and DB.
3. Keep state in local storage, write full changes to DB when "session" closes
4. ?

Comment: Can you share us the component that should be rendering correctly with data?

Comment: I think I know what is your issue come from, but I want to be sure

Comment: I figured it out. I just wasn't fetching the data again after the post -_-

Comment: I don't understand, you need to fetch again? on client side?

Comment: Yes.  Changes were being made to the DB, but I never had these actions dispatched to the reducers (they were just dispatched as posts to the DB)